# Trouble starting Ruby console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am fairly new to Ruby. I am have a problem getting my console to start a second time. I created my app (JacksApp) and created a model for it. I then shut down the app tried to restart the console a second time. When I type "rails c" I get this:

Running via Spring preloader in process 81129
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
No entry for terminal type "1.0.0/libexec:/Users/johnseabolt/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin";
using dumb terminal settings.
irb(main):001:0>

I don't understand what's going on. Can someone help? I am in the directory for the app. I'm confused.

Comment: It looks like [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is running in the background. You might not have intended to run it. Have you tried killing the spring process (`kill -9 81129`; the process id is from the error message)  and then running `rails c`?

Answer (score 5):

On MacOS Sierra, check TERM in Terminal.app

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ bin/spring stop
$ bin/rails c
No entry for terminal type "local/var/ry/rubies";
using dumb terminal settings.
irb> exit
$ bin/rails c
Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
```

You can change TERM via Terminal > Preference > Profiles > Advanced > Terminfo > Declare terminal as: xterm.

Open new Terminal.

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm
$ bin/rails c
irb>
```

All sweet no warnings.

Now I leave it to someone with greater knowledge to explain why.

Comment: For iTerm you can find the Terminal setting in Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal -> Report Terminal Type

You'll need to start a new terminal session (tab) for changes to take effect

Answer (score 4):

to fix this, you need to stop all rails processes and stop spring (bin/spring stop) and then make sure that you start up spring with an attached terminal.

There are basically three ways where spring would get started: bundle exec rails server, bundle exec rails console, or something like bundle exec guard or some other testing thing.  If you start up rails through foreman, then it will run one of these commands, basically.

Starting the console will attach a input to the process, and this is where it will figure out the "terminal" type.  Do that first, before everything thing else.  Once that's loaded in memory, then its configured correctly, and starting up server or whatever will work find.

Server then console will give you the crazy error that you see.  console then server will not.

Answer (score 1):

Does it still let you use the console? The `irb(main):001:0>` at the end suggests that it is indeed working, you're just getting a warning about your terminal type setting being missing.

To fix the warning...If you're using a 3rd party terminal emulator, I'd reinstall that and see if that fixes it. Otherwise you can manually set your terminal type using `export TERM=xxx` in your `~/.bashrc` file.